# Setting the testcase parameters in Allure Report using WDIO's AllureReporter and Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, allure, wdio

In Java, when building [Allure Reports](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_test_case_page), you can set test case parameters like browser, browser version, browser type (e.g., headless), etc.

In [WDIO's AllureReporter](https://webdriver.io/docs/allure-reporter/) extension, I am unable to successfully set any environment variables using AllureReporter, such as

`allureReporter.addEnvironment("staging")`

or

`allureReporter.addArgument("browserType", "Firefox")`

Am I using these functions correctly? Is there another way to set these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to use Allure Reporter's `addArgument` in the `beforeTest` hook in my configuration file.

```
beforeTest: async function (test, context) {
    allure.addArgument("Browser", browser.capabilities["browserName"]);
    allure.addArgument("Platform", browser.capabilities["platformName"]);
    allure.addArgument("Platform Version", browser.capabilities["platformVersion"]);
},
```